# IMAP/POP3 with Dovecot & Postfix: Authentication Failed

Tags: email, postfix, authentication, dovecot

Says it all in the title. To give you some background, I'm a programmer. I'm not into installing mail servers as a hobby, and I'm having to make one because the project I'm creating will need to use a webmail type service (like roundcube, or my own creation).

My problem comes about when I'm trying to install Dovecot/Postfix and configure SMTP and IMAP services to work properl (excuse me if I use some of these words improperly). **I have tried everything to try and gain access via login (telnet, webmail [roundcube], and external software(s) such as email clients (via desktop)).**

In telnet, here's what happens when I try logging into either "my" IMAP/email account, or the "admin" IMAP/email account.

```
user@server:~/# telnet server.com imap
Trying 11.11.11.11...
Connected to server.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=LOGIN] Dovecot ready.
LOGIN logan password
LOGIN BAD First parameter in line is IMAP's command tag, not the command name. Add that before the command, like: a login user pass
a1 LOGIN logan password
a1 NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Authentication failed.
a1 LOGIN admin password
a1 NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Authentication failed.
a1 LOGIN admin
a1 BAD Error in IMAP command received by server.
a1 LOGIN logan 06E0AF9E904FE4CD9D743B4A06ECB3D9467CF9DF
a1 NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Authentication failed
```

With regards to the `06E0AF9E904FE4CD9D743B4A06ECB3D9467CF9DF`, all this is, is a SHA-1 hashed password for added security. I have both plain-text passwords set and hashed passwords to see if that was the issue, and it didnt help; or it messed it up more.

In roundcube, this is `error` log file within the `/logs` directory of my webmail installation.

Here are just some of the lines:

```
[17-Nov-2016 02:16:04 -0500]: <0nskdl6a> IMAP Error: Login failed for admin@server.com from 1.1.1.1. AUTHENTICATE PLAIN: Authentication failed. in /var/www/mail/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_imap.php on line 193 (POST /mail/?_task=login&_action=login)
[17-Nov-2016 02:16:22 -0500]: <0nskdl6a> IMAP Error: Login failed for admin from 1.1.1.1. AUTHENTICATE PLAIN: Authentication failed. in /var/www/mail/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_imap.php on line 193 (POST /mail/?_task=login&_action=login)
[17-Nov-2016 02:17:19 -0500]: <0nskdl6a> IMAP Error: Login failed for logan from 1.1.1.1. AUTHENTICATE PLAIN: Authentication failed. in /var/www/mail/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_imap.php on line 193 (POST /mail/?_task=login&_action=login)
[17-Nov-2016 02:17:52 -0500]: <0nskdl6a> IMAP Error: Login failed for logan@server.com from 1.1.1.1. AUTHENTICATE PLAIN: Authentication failed. in /var/www/mail/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_imap.php on line 193 (POST /mail/?_task=login&_action=login)
[17-Nov-2016 02:18:20 -0500]: <0nskdl6a> IMAP Error: Login failed for logan@server.com from 1.1.1.1. AUTHENTICATE PLAIN: Authentication failed. in /var/www/mail/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_imap.php on line 193 (POST /mail/?_task=login&_action=login)
[17-Nov-2016 02:26:55 -0500]: <0nskdl6a> IMAP Error: Login failed for logan@server.com from 1.1.1.1. AUTHENTICATE PLAIN: Authentication failed. in /var/www/mail/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_imap.php on line 193 (POST /mail/?_task=login&_action=login)
[17-Nov-2016 02:28:53 -0500]: <0nskdl6a> IMAP Error: Login failed for logan@server.com from 1.1.1.1. AUTHENTICATE PLAIN: Authentication failed. in /var/www/mail/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_imap.php on line 193 (POST /mail/?_task=login&_action=login)
[17-Nov-2016 02:33:38 -0500]: <0nskdl6a> IMAP Error: Login failed for logan from 1.1.1.1. AUTHENTICATE PLAIN: Authentication failed. in /var/www/mail/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_imap.php on line 193 (POST /mail/?_task=login&_action=login)
```

I've tried using the full email address, as well as just the username for the given defined users under `/etc/postfix/vmail_mailbox`

Thanks, and any help is greatly appreciated (and I hope I'm in the right place).

Comment: Please have a look at Dovecot's logs, and enable `auth_verbose=yes` and `auth_debug=yes`. What's Dovecot saying about those failed logins?

Comment: where can I find Dovecot's logs, and those configuration settings you're referencing?